# ListBox event to handle selection

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a ListBox with multiple ListBoxItems within it. I'd like to have one function handle each selection so I don't have to create an event for each ListBoxItem being selected. (Like how Menu and MenuItems works.)

Basically, each time a new selection is made a new UserControl is loaded into a Grid depending on what's selected.

What's the event to use for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="MyFunction" />
```